# Having a hard time cloning a repo from Github

Tags: git, github

I used to clone my repos using my user and password. After the update that forces you to use a PAT I no longer can clone. How do I use that token to clone using the terminal.

I've tried to clone using git clone repot.git
I am asked to enter my user and password but I in the end I get the message saying that user/password login is no longer available.

I saw some people using this method and a dialog appears to enter the access token but that dialog didn't appear for me.

Comment: Create PAT https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: I've created but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Use it instead of the password

Comment: I've visited many questions they are all different none worked for me I believe it's my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

When you're prompted to enter your username and password, enter your username as the username, and then enter your personal access token as the password.

Don't try to type it in by hand; instead, copy and paste it.  There's a copy button next to the token in the interface.  It may be the case that pasting doesn't echo back the value; that's normal and expected.  Once you've entered it, just hit Enter at the password prompt.

Git is a project that works with many different systems, and when using HTTPS, the authentication type used is Basic, which defines these two pieces as the username and password.  In GitHub's case, the password needs to be a personal access token, not the password you use for the web interface.